# data-uk-grid-margin attribute is not working in UIkit 2.x and 3.0

Tags: uikit, getuikit

I'm trying to create a grid of elements using [UIkit](https://getuikit.com/v2/docs/core.html)
 Front-End Framework.The problem is when I add `data-uk-grid-margin` to set margin between elements it does not give me any change.I don't know exactly where is my mistake,but I think a UIkit javascript file is missed in my code.

This is my snippet :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="uikit-2.27.5/css/uikit.min.css" />
        <script src="uikit-2.27.5/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
        <script src="uikit-2.27.5/js/uikit.js"></script>
        <script src="uikit-2.27.5/js/uikit-icons.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="uk-container">
      <ul class="uk-grid uk-align-center uk-margin" data-uk-grid-margin>
        <li class="uk-width-1-3">
          <div class="uk-panel uk-panel-box">
              <div class="uk-panel-badge uk-badge"></div>
              <h3 class="uk-panel-title">Title</h3>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </div></li>
            <li class="uk-width-1-3">    <div class="uk-panel uk-panel-box">
                  <div class="uk-panel-badge uk-badge"></div>
                  <h3 class="uk-panel-title">Title</h3>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                </div></li>
                <li class="uk-width-1-3">    <div class="uk-panel uk-panel-box">
                      <div class="uk-panel-badge uk-badge"></div>
                      <h3 class="uk-panel-title">Title</h3>
                      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                    </div></li>
                    <li class="uk-width-1-3">    <div class="uk-panel uk-panel-box">
                          <div class="uk-panel-badge uk-badge"></div>
                          <h3 class="uk-panel-title">Title</h3>
                          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                        </div></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

In addition ,I'm using Atom plugin for UIkit to help me with autocomplete ,but
the suggestions of javascript attributes are missed too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're calling:

- **jQuery** first (2.1.1 here just because SO snippet offered it)
- only one Uikit javascript file (uikit.min.js preferably)

*Working example below*

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/2.27.5/css/uikit.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/2.27.5/js/uikit.min.js"></script>

<div class="uk-container">
  <ul class="uk-grid uk-align-center uk-margin" data-uk-grid-margin>
    <li class="uk-width-1-3">
      <div class="uk-panel uk-panel-box">
        <div class="uk-panel-badge uk-badge"></div>
        <h3 class="uk-panel-title">Title</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="uk-width-1-3">
      <div class="uk-panel uk-panel-box">
        <div class="uk-panel-badge uk-badge"></div>
        <h3 class="uk-panel-title">Title</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="uk-width-1-3">
      <div class="uk-panel uk-panel-box">
        <div class="uk-panel-badge uk-badge"></div>
        <h3 class="uk-panel-title">Title</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="uk-width-1-1">
      <div class="uk-panel uk-panel-box">
        <div class="uk-panel-badge uk-badge"></div>
        <h3 class="uk-panel-title">Title</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not using CDN ,so it should  I download jquery packages and I add them to project.

Comment: yes, you can use local copy on your server. I'm using CDN here just to make the example work